# Windows AppFabric Auto-Start not starting WCF service

Tags: .net, wcf, azure, servicebus

I have been fighting with this all night, so here goes:

I have a Azure Service Bus WCF service, called Send.  I want to use Windows 2008 R2 (standard) server to host this in IIS using Windows Server AppFabric's Auto-Start Feature.

I have installed Windows Server AppFabric, it seemed to go smoothly.  However, I am missing the Auto-Start option in the UI you would normally get by right clicking the Website node in IIS, it should look like this:

http://developers.de/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/CommunityServer.Blogs.Components.WeblogFiles/damir_5F00_dobric/image_5F00_40F1B83A.png

However, I used the powershell commands instead, and they seemed to work.  The option to selectively auto-start a service did enable. So, I figured it should be working.  But, it does not auto start, I also do not get any errors in the eventlogs.  Below is my web config:

```
  <!-- Service Bus Service -->
  <service name="TestWeb.Send" behaviorConfiguration="serviceBusBehavior">
    <endpoint address="sb://mynamespace.servicebus.windows.net/Send/" contract="TestWeb.ISend" binding="netTcpRelayBinding" behaviorConfiguration="SharedSecretCredentials" />
  </service>

</services>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="serviceBusBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata />
    </behavior>       
  </serviceBehaviors>

  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="SharedSecretCredentials">
      <transportClientEndpointBehavior credentialType="SharedSecret">
        <clientCredentials>
          <sharedSecret issuerName="owner" issuerSecret="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=" />
        </clientCredentials>
      </transportClientEndpointBehavior>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>

</behaviors>
```

My service contract is pretty basic:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ISend
{
    [OperationContract]
    void SendMail(String Subject, String To, String Text, String HTML);
}
```

I also added the ServiceBus_schema.xml into the correct folder under Inetserv following the directions from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg282466

If I actually go to the service in a browser, it loads up fine, and I see the Service Bus register the endpoint.  But, it should be doing that without me doing anything at this point.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I will answer my own question because I finally figured it out.  I was trying to auto start a service in a root website.  It turns out it needs to be an application added off an existing web site.  It would be nice if they said that somewhere.  All of my options showed up and the service did actaully auto start.

Comment: resurecting an old thread - can you expand on exactly the hierachy you had in IIS that you managed to get working please?